# Sublime Text: Make cursor stay put upon pasting?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

For example:

```
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somemorestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
```

Want to assign `class="abc"` to each one.

Now I realize there is the Ctrl+Alt+Arrows to "carve" out a vertical path of cursors (neat trick!) after which point I can paste in my class, but that won't work if my div's are separated by some lines.

So I'd like to paste:

```
<div class="abc">somestuff</div>
<div>somemorestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
<div>somestuff</div>
```

But it puts my cursor HERE

```
<div class="abc"|>somestuff</div>
```

I'd like for it to stay here

```
<div| class="abc">somestuff</div>
```

so that I can just repeat <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best way to achieve what you need is to use command `split selection into lines`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac).

1. Select all the lines that you need to edit
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
3. Move the cursors (with arrow keys) in the position where you want to paste your code
4. Paste your code.

If you really want the the cursor to stay at the beginning of the pasted text, you can create a plug-in. `Tools/New Plugin...`:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class PasteAndResetCursorPositionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        start_region = self.view.sel()[0]
        self.view.window().run_command("paste")
        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(start_region)
```

Save this in your `Packages/User` directory.

Then add the key binding to your `Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+v"], "command": "paste_and_reset_cursor_position" }
```

Of course you can use the shortcut that you prefer.

Comment: great plugin solution. I am tempted to make the regular paste function that way.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do would be to select `<div`, then do <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> to select each identical text.  Then you can move your cursor on every one accordingly.

Comment: Even faster, select ```<div```, then **CTRL+CMD+G** to "Quick Find All"! Then, **right-arrow** and **CTRL+V** and you're done! :-)

Comment: But then he wouldn't have control over which `div`'s are selected if this block of code is nested in a bigger document.  Good tip though if you don't have any other code in the file.

Comment: Good point, derek_duncan! I was probably a bit too enthusiastic about the Quick Find All :-)

Comment: Indeed this is a good way to tackle this but I'd still like to know about cursor control with pasting

Comment: You can check sublime's website and see if it is supported in sublime3.  If not, now is the prime time to suggest it because it is in development.

Answer (score 0):

I like the plugin solution, and think that there's *one more* solution worth mentioning, especially since the question specifically calls for the simplicity of just hitting "down, ctrl+v" repeatedly...

Put your cursor where you want to enter the text, and use `shift+ctrl+down` to "multiply" your cursor points onto as many lines as necessary. Type what you want, and hit `esc` to return to a single point cursor.

Similar to @derek_duncan's answer, but with more granular control, assuming the text you're editing is lined up as in your example.

Comment: Yes, my answer doesn't cover *pasting*, but I thought was worth mentioning, for those that aren't used to -- or unaware that they can use -- multi-cursor editing.

Comment: Yeah depending on OSX or Windows it's either Ctrl+Alt or Shift+Ctrl that does this. I tend to use this more actually now.